# How to place multiple bitmaps in a scrollable rectangle? AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmap

This code builds a palette of tiles for use in a map maker program. It takes in an array set by its parent and uses the bitmaps(from the objects) in that array to display a grid of tiles. Right now it only does a 5x5 grid, but what if there are more than 25 tiles in my tileSet? I want to display only the 5x5 tile grid, but be able to scroll through the images. I imagine that I need to make another rectangle to use as its mask and use a ScrollBar to make it scrollRect, but I can't get this working. Please Help.

```
public function Palette(X:uint, Y:uint, tileSet:Array) 
    {
        addChild(handleGraphics);

        var palette:Rectangle = new Rectangle(X, Y, 5*32, tileSet.length*32); //Default size is 5x5 tiles.
        handleGraphics.DrawGrid(32,palette.x,palette.y,5,5);

        var counter:int = 0;

        for(var i:int = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            paletteArray[i] = [];

            for(var u:int = 0; u < 5; u++)
            {
                if(counter >= tileSet.length)
                {
                    counter = 0; //Which frame to show?
                }
                var b:Bitmap = new Bitmap(tileSet[counter].Graphic);
                b.x = (palette.x) + 32 * u; //Align with palette Rectangle.
                b.y = (palette.y) + 32 * i; ///////////////////////////////
                addChild(b);

                var tileObj:Object = new Object();
                tileObj.Name = tileSet[counter].Name;
                tileObj.Frame = tileSet[counter].Frame;
                tileObj.Graphic = tileSet[counter].Graphic;
                paletteArray[i].push(tileObj);

                setChildIndex(b, 0); //Under grid.
                counter++;
            }
        }
        ActivatePaletteListeners();
    }
```

This code works great for a tileSet array that has less than 25 objects. It loops and shows them continuously until it hits 25. I could do without this I guess, but it is a neat affect.

---

In another class (HandleTiles) I cycle through my tileSet MovieClip and use each frame to create a new object for each tile.

```
public function GetPaletteTiles(MC:MovieClip)
    {
        if (tileArray != null)
        {
            tileArray.length = 0;
        }

        for(var i:int = 1; i <= MC.totalFrames; i++)
        {
            MC.gotoAndStop(i); //Change frame for new info.

            var tileObj:Object = new Object(); //The object to push to an array of tiles.
            var graphicData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(32,32);
            graphicData.draw(MC); //Graphic data from sampleTS.

            tileObj.Name = MC.currentFrameLabel;
            tileObj.Frame = MC.currentFrame;
            tileObj.Graphic = graphicData;

            tileArray.push(tileObj);
        }
        BuildIndexArray(15, 20); //Default size 15 x 20.
    }
```

And here I set the tileSet to use

```
private function ChangeActiveTileset(Mc:MovieClip)
    {
        activeTileset = Mc;
        GetPaletteTiles(activeTileset);
        UpdatePalette();
    }
```

I can change the tileSet with a comboBox. That's why I tear down the tileArray every time I call GetPaletteTiles(). Each tileSet is a different MovieClip, like Buildings, Samples, InTheCity, etc.

Comment: It looks like you're not using movieclips.  You should use movieclips, not index.  Put the bmps in movieclips - mcMap can be map bmp tiles or can contain sub mcs.  You can use sub movieclips no problem, it's getting everything into bmp that really matters.  Store references for everything (bmps, mcs, etc.) in arrays - aMapTiles[i].

Comment: The tileset that it takes is an array full of objects created from a single movie clip. And then I do store the new objects that this creates in paletteArray. I don't see how your answer has anything to do with what I asked. Creating a new movie clip for every tile is what I'm trying to avoid. It's horrible on performance.

Comment: Never said to do create a new clip or whatever.  I'm clear on performance.  If you're using scrollRect or masking, you're not clear on performance.  So you're not asking how to make a gpu-optimized tiled-bmp image?  You're asking how to change your loops or add a loop?

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding you. You said that I should use movie clips. I thought you meant making each tile a movie clip,  which is how I was doing it when I first started this. And what do you mean by sub movie clips? Like nested movie clips? I was really asking about how to change my loops and how to use a scroll bar with it, but if you know of a better way then I'd rather do that. If maybe you could give an example of your way I would greatly appreciate it

Comment: In general, the most effective method is just to draw movieclips to bmp - make everything bmp (max dimensions set by size of device display).  Once the mc is nothing but bmp, it can be moved normally (regular flash movement) at 60fps.  You don't need to blit or do anything special.  You can just throw whatever you want into the movieclip and turn the movieclip into bmp tiles.  Want the code I use to do it this way?

Comment: I think that's the way I'm already doing it.i have all of my tiles on different frames of a movie clip and then I loop through every frame to make an object from each one with properties like name, frame number, and graphic. That's why I'm doing tileArray[counter].Graphic to display only the bitmap image of each tile. If I'm still confusing your method I'm sure seeing it would help

Comment: I edited my question to show my use of MovieClips

Comment: I didn't realize that the Tile List component was exactly what I needed. I didn't even know it existed. Maybe it's not ideal for performance but it works wonderfully!! Thanks a lot for your help, moot... and I'm still interested in how you did it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I didn't have time to get this code together earlier.  Here's tiling code pieces.  Because you're using rectangle and you have to stay under max dimensions you have to move the source mc.  I think you already know everything else in there.

```
//  set the bmp dimensions to device screensize to prevent exceeding device's max bmp dimensions
if (bStagePortrait) {
    iTileWidth = Capabilities.screenResolutionX;
    iTileHeight = Capabilities.screenResolutionY;
} else {
    iTileWidth = Capabilities.screenResolutionY;
    iTileHeight = Capabilities.screenResolutionX;
}

//  mcList.mcListVector is the source mc - a regular mc containing mcs, jpgs, dynamic text, vector shapes, etc.
//  mcList.mcListBmp is an empty mc

aListTiles = new Array();
iNumberOfTiles = Math.ceil(mcList.height / iTileHeight);

for (i = 0; i < iNumberOfTiles; i++) {
    var bmpTile: Bitmap;
    //  move the source mc
    mcList.mcListVector.y = -(i * iTileHeight);
    bmpTile = fDrawTile(mcList, 0, 0, iTileWidth, iTileHeight);
    mcList.mcListBmp.addChild(bmpTile);
    bmpTile.x = 0;
    bmpTile.y = (i * iTileHeight);
    aListTiles.push(bmpTile);
}

//  remove the regular mc
mcList.mcListVector.removeChild(mcList.mcListVector.mcPic);
mcList.mcListVector.mcPic = null;
mcList.removeChild(mcList.mcListVector);
mcList.mcListVector = null;
}


function fDrawTile(pClip: MovieClip, pX: int, pY: int, pWidth: int, pHeight: int): Bitmap {
    trace("fDrawTile: " + pX + "," + pY + "  " + pWidth + "," + pHeight);
    var rectTemp: Rectangle = new Rectangle(pX, pY, pWidth, pHeight);
    var bdClip: BitmapData = new BitmapData(pWidth, pHeight, true, 0x00000000);
    var bdTemp: BitmapData = new BitmapData(pWidth, pHeight, true, 0x00000000);
    bdClip.draw(pClip, null, null, null, rectTemp, true);
    bdTemp.copyPixels(bdClip, rectTemp, new Point(0, 0));
    var bmpReturn: Bitmap = new Bitmap(bdTemp, "auto", true);
    return bmpReturn;
}
```